# Study of the subgroups of which a non-linear monomial character is induced from

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, character-theory

Let G be a monomial group, and let H_1,...,H_r be the subgroups of G where there exists a linear character that induces to an irreducible character of G. How much is known about these subgroups? For example: What can be said about their intersection, which ones are normal, etc?

I ask because I have found some results related to this, and I want to know what there exists of current theory on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

One nice theorem I know in this direction is a beautiful result of U. Riese which states that if $A$ is an Abelian subgroup of $G$ such that ${\rm Ind}_{A}^{G}(\lambda)$ is irreducible for some linear character $\lambda$ of $A$, then $A \lhd \lhd G.$

*Riese, Udo*, [**A subnormality criterion in finite groups related to character degrees**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1997.7259), J. Algebra 201, No. 2, 357-362 (1998). [ZBL0915.20004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0915.20004).

Comment: For those (like me until now) who don't know this notation: $A \triangleleft \triangleleft\: G$ apparently means that $A$ is a subnormal subgroup of $G$: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Notation_for_subgroup_properties